# How to activate 3d view and save the revit model in design automation api for Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am working on a task where I need to accept a template file (.rte) as input and save the resultant revit file in 3d view.

I understand that to activate 3d view, we need `UIDocument` which is not available when we work in DesignAutomation API.

In an addin project in the past I had implemented it in the following way:

```cs
FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(View3D));

foreach (View3D v in collector)
{
    if (!v.IsTemplate)
    {
        uiApp.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView = v;
    }
}
```

So is there any other way to do this in DesignAutomation API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have no access whatsoever to the `UIDocument` in the Design Automation API. It does not even exist. I suggest you just go ahead and generate your Revit model as before and then see what view ends up being saved. Quite possibly it is the 3D view anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. its the top view that is generated as output and  not 3d view

Comment: Aha. Well, the 3D view exists, generally. It is normally named `{3D}`, I believe. You can activate it using... oops... [Document.Active.View is read-only](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/043960ac-dde4-0f45-249f-8161646a4362.htm)... `UIDocument` is not available... don't know. Why do you care what view is active? It doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: Actually, the scenario is that I am drawing a ceiling, but when I download the file as output from forge api, the ceiling is drawn but it can't be seen in the default view that is opened. Hence I am asked to save in a 3d view

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion on [setting the preview image](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/05/set-preview-image.html) from which you may be able to glean some hints.